# Why is the internal hom of a Kan complex also a Kan complex?

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let $X, Y : \Delta^{op} \to \text{Set}$ be simplicial sets. I've seen it stated that if $Y$ is a Kan complex, then the internal hom $Y^X$ is a Kan complex also. How does one show this?

Comment: This might be naive, but I would start as follows: For a horn inclusion $\Lambda^n_i \subseteq \Delta^n$ one has to show that $\hom(\Delta^n,Y^X) \to \hom(\Lambda^n_i,Y^X)$ is surjective. This maps identifies with $\hom(\Delta^n \times X,Y) \to \hom(\Lambda^n_i \times X,Y)$. So it suffices to prove that $\Lambda^n_i \to \Delta^n$ is anodyne, i.e. can be "generated" by Horn inclusions via transfinite compositions and pushouts. Well, it seams reasonable to do the case $X=\Delta^m$ first, and then somehow make a colimit argument.

Comment: There is an argument of that type in [Goerss and Jardine, Ch. I, §4].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allegedly, one can prove this directly, but I have never seen the details. (For instance, the same fact is asserted without proof as Theorem 1.9 in [Moore, *Semi-simplicial complexes and Postnikov systems*].)  Here is a more high-level proof.

Recall that the class of anodyne extensions of simplicial sets is defined by induction:

- Any horn inclusion is an anodyne extension.
- Any pushout of an anodyne extension is an anodyne extension.
- Any finite or transfinite composite of anodyne extensions is an anodyne extension.

It immediately follows that a simplicial set $K$ is a Kan complex if and only if the unique morphism $K \to \Delta^0$ has the right lifting property with respect to all anodyne extensions.

Let $X$ be a simplicial set and let $Y$ be a Kan complex. We wish to show that $Y^X$ is a Kan complex. By adjointness, $Y^X$ is a Kan complex if and only if $Y \to \Delta^0$ has the right lifting property with respect to all morphisms of the form $i \times \mathrm{id}_X$ where $i$ is an anodyne extension. But it is well known that a morphism is an anodyne extension if and only if it is both a monomorphism and a weak homotopy equivalence, so $i \times \mathrm{id}_X$ is an anodyne extension if $i$ is. Thus $Y^X$ is indeed a Kan complex.

Comment: Can you generalize this argument to all model categories? Specifically if $i$ is an acyclic cofibration, is $i \times id_X$ an acyclic cofibration too?

Comment: No. It only works for sufficiently nice model categories, e.g. cartesian model categories in which all objects are cofibrant and cofibrations = monomorphisms.